# how to display items in view dynamically in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display items in view in mvc dynamically.
following is the code for displaying records in view

```
@using MvcWcf.ServiceReference1
@model IEnumerable<WcfService.MyAddress> 

<table> 
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address1)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)</td>
  </tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address1)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</td>     
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

my requirement how to display items in th and records dynamically
for example `<td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address1)</td><td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)</td>`
here i wrote `address1` and `City`  because i know the fields.
if i don't know the fields how to display that.
also in displaying records

Comment: What do you mean you don't know the fields? The model is typeof `MyAddress` so so know its properties.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? what do you mean by dynamically ?

Comment: I think he want to have a generic model for the view that have from 1 to N elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic model with this property

```
public List<GenericItem> items { get; set; }
```

than you create your generic item with the property you need, like type (textbox, button, ...), text inside and anything you need

```
public class GenericItem
{
    public enum Type { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

than you must create a custom helper (like a custom editorfor) that accepts a generic model and with that model show on screen the appropriate control with what you have inside your model.

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs